# Minecraft Redstone delay that only works if active for 5 seconds but turns off when not active

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

[image]
The image here is my example. the command block to the left places a redstone block on the quartz. the command blocks on the side remove the Redstone block and replace the repeaters. this method still doesn't work.
Edit: so the problem is that with is method even with the repeaters getting replaced, somehow the signal still moves. I think the problem is that I set the repeaters to a delay, so the signal still moves.
So if I were to stand on a pressure plate, how would I make the pulse wait but as soon as I'm not on the pressure plate, the pulse stops?
even when I set the repeaters with a 2 tick delay, they still moved the pulse a long.

I've tried having the pressure plate hook up to a command that places a Redstone block then removes it when it isn't active, but that still makes the output still activate even when I'm not standing on the pressure plate.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: I have, but it seems like it just doesn't work. What I'm looking for is a delay that completely turns off when it isn't active.

Comment: Showing us what you've tried is super helpful.  That way, we know where you're going, and can show you where you're stuck.

Comment: What do you mean with "turning off a delay"? Do you want to immediately turn the output on when the input turns on and wait a bit after the input turns off before you turn the output off? And what is this all for?

Comment: We are trying to clarify what you want.  Your explanation is confusing.  My take: You want to step on the pressure plate, five seconds later the signal goes high, and if you step off the pressure plate, the signal goes low immediately?

Comment: @IronAnvil that is exactly what I want, sorry for being so vague.

Comment: You should submit your edited post as an answer. Editing your post with your answer gets rid of the question, which makes the post difficult to follow. You can access your edited post by going into the edit history (you can click the "edited x minutes ago" label to get there).

Comment: Thanks for that, I am really clueless on this site. I'll try to avoid all these issues next time!

Comment: No problem! And you can accept your own answer as well by clicking the checkmark next to your post. That way people can see that this is the answer that helped you the most. (In this case I guess it doesn't matter too much since it's the only answer, but it's still nice for consistency). Thanks, and welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution  [image]
Ok, so the two command blocks linked to the clock are placing and removing the block between the comparator and the repeating command block. the command block is testing where if someone is standing on the quartz. the command block that is linked to gives everyone XP. it does this as long as someone is standing on the block and cancels if someone isn't. What I wanted was for someone to stand on a block, and it kept on giving them XP. but the problem with just having it test for and then send out a signal is that even when they aren't standing on it, they still get the XP. but if I make it a one-time thing and check it constantly, then it will work. I am sorry everyone for the confusion I gave you. So in the end, using scoreboards are the best way to have a delay that can be stopped immediately.